# Split list according to the rule

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list

```
values_list = [1013.0, 683.0, 336.0, 406.0, 636.0, 1065.0, 1160.0]
```

Also I have a value

```
value = 660.6153846153846
```

This list is based on the assumption that there are 3 stages. First stage should be higher that the **value**, second - lower, and third is again higher.

I want to split this list into three lists, saving the order of the values like this:

```
values_list = [[1013.0, 683.0], [336.0, 406.0, 636.0], [1065.0, 1160.0]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post in your question examples of your achievements so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one, using [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

values_list = [1013.0, 683.0, 336.0, 406.0, 636.0, 1065.0, 1160.0]
value = 660.6153846153846

result = list(list(b) for a,b in groupby(values_list, lambda x: x < value ))
print (result)
```

Result:

```
[[1013.0, 683.0], [336.0, 406.0, 636.0], [1065.0, 1160.0]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
splits = []
splt = []
s = 0
for v in values_list:
    if len(splt) > 0:
        if v > value and s != 1:
            splits.append(splt)
            splt = []
        elif v <= value and s != -1:
            splits.append(splt)
            splt = []
    splt.append(v)
    s = 2*(v > value) - 1
if len(splt) > 0:
    splits.append(splt)
```

Comment: For me it returns `[[1013.0, 683.0], [336.0, 406.0, 636.0], [1065.0, 1160.0]]`.

Comment: Correct. I got same output as you now.